# Prevent SVN users from reading logs from folders they are unauthorized to read

Tags: svn

I have path level access control setup for our SVN server that works fine for managing r/w permissions for various SVN folders.  I've noticed that users who are not authorized to read Folder B can still view the log file for Folder B when they browse the Revision Graph in TortoiseSVN.  It only happens (presumably) in the case that Folder B is originally a branch off of Folder A, which they do have r/w access to.  I'm sure this is a side effect of the branch, but is there a way to fix it?  Ideally the branch doesn't need to be broken off because there have been times when data from the trunk has been merged over to the RnD side.